# fgetc stops when recognizing new line (\n)

Tags: c, file, newline, fgetc

I have this code:

```
while( (cCurrent = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
{

}
```

The problem is, when it hits a new line it stops reading.

What would be a good way to ignore the newline character?

Edit:

I'm trying to create a file crypter.
It is able to encrypt the file, but the decrypt process won't work.
It works till the end of the first line, but it won't continue to the next characters in the file.

For example, for the text file:

```
Foo  
Bar
```

After the encryption the result is:

> Xu||Gb|t

After the decryption the result is:

> ```
> FooRqb
> ```

I concluded that the new line char was the problem. maybe it wasn't.

My code is:

```
/* check if the file is openable */
if( (fp = fopen(szFileName, "r+")) != NULL )
{
    /* save current position */
    currentPos = ftell(fp);
    /* get the current byte and check if it is EOF, if not then loop */
    while( (cCurrent = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        /* XOR it */
        cCurrent ^= 0x10;
        /* take the position indicator back to the last position before read byte */
        fseek(fp, currentPos, SEEK_SET);
        /* set the current byte */
        fputc(cCurrent, fp);
        /* reset stream for next read operation */
        fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_CUR);
        /* save current position */
        currentPos = ftell(fp);
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps get a C compiler that works? This is not the correct behavior for `fgetc()`.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but if you want to ignore(skip) newlines, an `if (cCurrent == '\n') continue;` in the loop may be what you want.

Comment: If `fp` is attached to a terminal `fgetc` will never return `EOF`. Instead it will block, waiting for more input from the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows, lines in text files are separated by `\r\n`, not just `\n`, and files are opened by default in "text" mode, which automatically translates `\r\n` to `\n` when reading the file (see [fopen in Visual Studio 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Since you're interpreting your file as a sequence of bytes (because of the XOR operation), you don't want this behavior - each time there is a line ending, you're losing a byte of data. You should open your file in "binary" mode to suppress this behavior:

```
fp = fopen(szFileName, "rb+")
```

This will also suppress the behavior noted by @Mike where reading a `\x1A` character is interpreted as the end of file.

Answer (score 7):

It took me a while, but I finally got what you're trying to do.

Input file:

```
Hello
```

encrypt by running your code:

```
Xu||(non displayable character)
```

Decrypt by running your code again:

```
Hello
```

So how this works:

```
0x48 XOR 0x10 = 0100 1000 (H)---+
                0001 0000       |
                ---------       V
                0101 1000 = 58 (X)

0x58 XOR 0x10 = 0101 1000 (X)---+
                0001 0000       |
                ---------       V
                0100 1000 = 48 (H)
```

The problem comes in with you're working with the new line character `'\n'` which is 0xA<sub>16</sub>

Input file:

```
Hello
You
```

This works fine up until the `'\n'` then we get new line:

```
0xA XOR 0x10 =  0000 1010 ('\n')---+
                0001 0000          |
                ---------          V
                0001 1010 = 1A (substitute character)
```

[The substitute character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character) In DOS operating systems, this character is used to indicate the end of a file (EOF)

So this fails *because* you're working on Windows. So you need to do special checking for the `'\n'` case in your encryption/decryption and not blindly XOR it.

One easy fix, you could simply do something like:

```
while( (cCurrent = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
{
    /* XOR it if it's not a '\n'*/
    if(cCurrent != '\n')
      cCurrent ^= 0x10;
```

Comment: impressive, I saw the 0x1a with hexdump, but didn't give it much thought as I've read in the wiki that EOF is not used by the OS to determine the file size, and that it was used on DOS only.

Comment: @user1718294 - Happy to help. It was a good question that took some thinking about. I'd up vote you but I ran out of up votes for the day. :)

Answer (score 2):

`fgetc` shouldn't stop at a newline character, only at `EOF`, from man [fgetc(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgetc):

> fgetc() reads the next character from stream and returns it as an
>   unsigned char cast to an int, or **EOF on end of file or error**.

If you however, write it like this:

```
while( (cCurrent = fgetc(fp)) != '\n' && cCurrent != EOF)
```

It *will stop* at the newline character, so the first one is correct:

```
while( (cCurrent = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
```

Comment: You are right, my solution wasn't good.
But still, it stops when it hits a new line.

Comment: @user1718294 how to you open the file ? do you open for reading and writing ? also your logic seems wrong, you keep resetting the file pointer so you read the characters you just wrote.

Comment: I'm using `fopen` with 'r+'.
I'm not reading the same characters that I wrote.
I'm writing to the same characters that I read.

Comment: @user1718294 that's correct, I've tried your code seems to be working well, I seem no problems, except that fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_CUR) is useless you don't need it, try with another text file maybe.

Comment: When I'm removing `fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_CUR);` it gets me into an infinite loop.

Comment: @user1718294 it shouldn't, that line does nothing, it seeks zero bytes from the current position.

Comment: Note
       that ANSI C requires that a file positioning function intervene between output
       and input, unless an input operation encounters end-of-file.  (If this
       condition is not met, then a read is allowed to return the result of writes
       other than the most recent.)  Therefore it is good practice (and indeed
       sometimes necessary under Linux) to put an fseek(3) or fgetpos(3) operation
       between write and read operations on such a stream.  This operation may be an apparent no-op (as in fseek(..., 0L, SEEK_CUR) called for its synchronizing
       side effect.

Comment: @user1718294 very good point ! unfortunately it's still the same, your code is working here fine, on Linux, encrypts and decrypts, with or without the seek.

Comment: @mux - see my answer as to why it's working on Linux, not on Windows

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct behavior for [fgetc()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgetc/).

Your second code snippet is puzzling as it does in fact break when you hit a newline. So how that resolves the issue is a mystery to me.

I suspect you have your logic mixed up a little.

Comment: You are right, my solution wasn't good.
But still, it stops when it hits a new line.